# After a Visual Studio 2019 update, all published files have a new timestamp

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I have updated Visual Studio 2019 from version 16.11.7 to 16.11.11. After that, I republished an ASP.NET (TargetFramework NET5.0) website after some changes.

In the publish folder, all files had a new timestamp. Even static files such as images, etc.

In the publish options, the option "Delete all existing files prior to publish" is unchecked.

Re-publishing leaves the timestamps of unchanged files unchanged - as usual. So the problem seems to occur only with Visual Studio updates.

Can Visual Studio 2019 be configured so that all files are not set with new timestamps after an update?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Why does the timestamp matter? Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: It matters since typical deployment processes are based on timestamp deltas. In normal cases only a couple of files are uploaded to the server. With this behaviour gigabytes of data could be uploaded.